# How edit/save config.php file from a form

Tags: php, forms, config

I have a file called config.php with contents that looks like this:

```
$setting_1 = "value1";
$setting_2 = "value2";
$setting_3 = "value3";
$setting_4 = "value4";
```

How can I use a form to edit/save these values from a webpage? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. if you have a config, use a config format: ini, xml, yaml, ect. 2. just google for form & file write functionality for php

Comment: @Hannes: Might not be the best idea to put restricted configuration values in an open format.. plus if writing the config file is a very rare process, you save a lot of time by having the config in a native format (which you can just include) later..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the values, you simply include the file (as you would when using the configuration). Then you can simply output the current configuration [at the appropriate location in the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949495/how-to-make-form-elements-remember-selection) to make it appear as the default (or current) value.

When you save it, you pass the values just as you would with a normal html form, and - after validation of the values - simply construct a new string that is in the exact format as the config file.

Then you open the file for writing and replace the contents by the new values.

Answer (score 0):

Make 4 input text boxes and save them into the settings array?

Google of "php form" and get many examples